# Spring security - Websphere token authentication along with Spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, websphere, ltpa

I have a spring boot application with simple database authentication Spring security. In lower environments, we use this and for higher environments(deployed in Webpshere application server) the request for the spring boot applications has LTPA token added to the headers.

My requirement is, when LTPA token is present, do not show Spring security login form and permit all requests. All requests in higher environments has this token.

If token is not present, show spring security and authenticate using database. I don't have to create any ltpa token here.